# Linking tables and table joins in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have pulled the SQL from a report and need to edit it. I understand I can edit the links in the database expert but I am getting different results.
Below is the query in the report that is currently setup but I want to change:

```
  SELECT "Shipments"."smpShipmentID", "ShipmentLines"."smlUnitOfMeasure", "Shipments"."smpCustomerOrganizationID", "ShippingMethods"."xasDescription", "SalesOrders"."ompFreeOnBoardDescription", "SalesOrders"."ompCustomerPO", "SalesOrderLines"."omlOrderQuantity", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderID", "SalesOrderLines"."omlQuantityShipped", "ShipmentLines"."smlShippedComplete", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderLineID", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderDeliveryID", "ShipmentLines"."smlShipmentLineID", "Shipments"."smpARInvoiceLocationID", "Shipments"."smpShipLocationID", "Shipments"."smpShipOrganizationID", "ShipmentLines"."smlUniqueID", "SalesOrders"."ompSalesOrderID", "SalesOrderLines"."omlPartID", "SalesOrderLines"."omlPartRevisionID", "SalesOrderLines"."omlPartShortDescription", "SalesOrderLines"."omlSalesOrderLineID", "SalesOrderLines"."uomlCustPOLine", "SalesOrderLines"."omlOrgPartID", "SalesOrderLines"."omlOrgPartShortDescription", "Shipments"."usmpPallets", "Shipments"."usmpCartons", "SalesOrders"."ompOrderDate", "Shipments"."smpTrackingNumber", "Projects"."uprpPrimeContractNumber", "Shipments"."smpShipDate", "Projects"."uprpDPASRating", "Organizations"."cmoOrganizationID", "Projects"."uprpITAR", "ShipmentLines"."smlWeightUnitOfMeasure", "Shipments"."usmpActualWeight", "ShipmentLines"."smlQuantityShipped", "SalesOrderDeliveries"."omdDeliveryDate", ({fn ifnull((select cmcName from m1_l1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpCustomerOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceContactID),'')}), ({fn ifnull((select Count(*) from m1_l1.dbo."SerialNumberTransactions" "SerialNumberTransactions" where "ShipmentLines"."smlUniqueID" = "SerialNumberTransactions"."sntTableUniqueID"),0)}), ({fn ifnull((select cmcFaxNumber from m1_l1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpCustomerOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceContactID),'')}), ({fn ifnull((select cmcPhoneNumber from m1_l1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpCustomerOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceContactID),'')}), ({fn ifnull((select Count(*) from m1_l1.dbo."LotNumberTransactions" "LotNumberTransactions" where "ShipmentLines"."smlUniqueID" = "LotNumberTransactions"."abtTableUniqueID"),0)}), ({fn ifnull((select cmcName from m1_l1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpShipOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpShipLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpShipContactID),'')}), ({fn ifnull((select cmcFaxNumber from m1_l1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpShipOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpShipLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpShipContactID),'')}), ({fn ifnull((select cmcPhoneNumber from m1_l1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpShipOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpShipLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpShipContactID),'')}), "ShipmentLines"."smlPartLongDescriptionRTF", "SalesOrders"."ompOrderCommentsText", "Shipments"."smpShippingCommentsText", "SalesOrders"."ompShippingInstructionsText", "Organizations"."cmoShippingInstructionsText"FROM   ((((((("m1_l1"."dbo"."Shipments" "Shipments" INNER JOIN "m1_l1"."dbo"."ShipmentLines" "ShipmentLines" ON "Shipments"."smpShipmentID"="ShipmentLines"."smlShipmentID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "m1_l1"."dbo"."ShippingMethods" "ShippingMethods" ON "Shipments"."smpShippingMethodID"="ShippingMethods"."xasShippingMethodID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "m1_l1"."dbo"."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" ON ((("Shipments"."smpShipLocationID"="OrganizationContacts"."cmcLocationID") AND ("Shipments"."smpShipContactID"="OrganizationContacts"."cmcContactID")) AND ("Shipments"."smpShipOrganizationID"="OrganizationContacts"."cmcOrganizationID") AND ("Shipments"."smpARInvoiceLocationID"="OrganizationContacts"."cmcContactID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "m1_l1"."dbo"."Organizations" "Organizations" ON "Shipments"."smpCustomerOrganizationID"="Organizations"."cmoOrganizationID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "m1_l1"."dbo"."Projects" "Projects" ON "Shipments"."smpProjectID"="Projects"."prpProjectID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "m1_l1"."dbo"."SalesOrders" "SalesOrders" ON "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderID"="SalesOrders"."ompSalesOrderID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "m1_l1"."dbo"."SalesOrderLines" "SalesOrderLines" ON ("ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderID"="SalesOrderLines"."omlSalesOrderID") AND ("ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderLineID"="SalesOrderLines"."omlSalesOrderLineID")) LEFT OUTER JOIN "m1_l1"."dbo"."SalesOrderDeliveries" "SalesOrderDeliveries" ON ("SalesOrderLines"."omlSalesOrderID"="SalesOrderDeliveries"."omdSalesOrderID") AND ("SalesOrderLines"."omlSalesOrderLineID"="SalesOrderDeliveries"."omdSalesOrderLineID") WHERE  "Shipments"."smpShipmentID"='16817' ORDER BY "Shipments"."smpShipmentID", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderID", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderLineID", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderDeliveryID", "ShipmentLines"."smlShipmentLineID"
```

Here is the SQL that works which only has a different join ON but I am not sure how to make the changes in the database expert links setup.

```
 SELECT "Shipments"."smpShipmentID", "ShipmentLines"."smlUnitOfMeasure", "Shipments"."smpCustomerOrganizationID", "ShippingMethods"."xasDescription", "SalesOrders"."ompFreeOnBoardDescription", "SalesOrders"."ompCustomerPO", "SalesOrderLines"."omlOrderQuantity", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderID", "SalesOrderLines"."omlQuantityShipped", "ShipmentLines"."smlShippedComplete", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderLineID", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderDeliveryID", "ShipmentLines"."smlShipmentLineID", "Shipments"."smpARInvoiceLocationID", "Shipments"."smpShipLocationID", "Shipments"."smpShipOrganizationID", "ShipmentLines"."smlUniqueID", "SalesOrders"."ompSalesOrderID", "SalesOrderLines"."omlPartID", "SalesOrderLines"."omlPartRevisionID", "SalesOrderLines"."omlPartShortDescription", "SalesOrderLines"."omlSalesOrderLineID", "SalesOrderLines"."uomlCustPOLine", "SalesOrderLines"."omlOrgPartID", "SalesOrderLines"."omlOrgPartShortDescription", "Shipments"."usmpPallets", "Shipments"."usmpCartons", "SalesOrders"."ompOrderDate", "Shipments"."smpTrackingNumber", "Projects"."uprpPrimeContractNumber", "Shipments"."smpShipDate", "Projects"."uprpDPASRating", "Organizations"."cmoOrganizationID", "Projects"."uprpITAR", "ShipmentLines"."smlWeightUnitOfMeasure", "Shipments"."usmpActualWeight", "ShipmentLines"."smlQuantityShipped", "SalesOrderDeliveries"."omdDeliveryDate", ({fn ifnull((select cmcName from m1_m1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpCustomerOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceContactID),'')}), ({fn ifnull((select Count(*) from m1_m1.dbo."SerialNumberTransactions" "SerialNumberTransactions" where "ShipmentLines"."smlUniqueID" = "SerialNumberTransactions"."sntTableUniqueID"),0)}), ({fn ifnull((select cmcFaxNumber from m1_m1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpCustomerOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceContactID),'')}), ({fn ifnull((select cmcPhoneNumber from m1_m1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpCustomerOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpARInvoiceContactID),'')}), ({fn ifnull((select Count(*) from m1_m1.dbo."LotNumberTransactions" "LotNumberTransactions" where "ShipmentLines"."smlUniqueID" = "LotNumberTransactions"."abtTableUniqueID"),0)}), ({fn ifnull((select cmcName from m1_m1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpShipOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpShipLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpShipContactID),'')}), ({fn ifnull((select cmcFaxNumber from m1_m1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpShipOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpShipLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpShipContactID),'')}), ({fn ifnull((select cmcPhoneNumber from m1_m1.dbo."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" where OrganizationContacts.cmcOrganizationID=Shipments.smpShipOrganizationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcLocationID = Shipments.smpShipLocationID and OrganizationContacts.cmcContactID = Shipments.smpShipContactID),'')}), "ShipmentLines"."smlPartLongDescriptionRTF", "SalesOrders"."ompOrderCommentsText", "Shipments"."smpShippingCommentsText", "SalesOrders"."ompShippingInstructionsText", "Organizations"."cmoShippingInstructionsText" FROM ((((((("M1_L1"."dbo"."Shipments" "Shipments" INNER JOIN "M1_L1"."dbo"."ShipmentLines" "ShipmentLines" ON "Shipments"."smpShipmentID"="ShipmentLines"."smlShipmentID") INNER JOIN "M1_L1"."dbo"."ShippingMethods" "ShippingMethods" ON "Shipments"."smpShippingMethodID"="ShippingMethods"."xasShippingMethodID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "M1_L1"."dbo"."OrganizationContacts" "OrganizationContacts" ON ((("Shipments"."smpShipLocationID"="OrganizationContacts"."cmcLocationID") AND ("Shipments"."smpShipContactID"="OrganizationContacts"."cmcContactID")) AND ("Shipments"."smpShipOrganizationID"="OrganizationContacts"."cmcOrganizationID")) AND ("Shipments"."smpARInvoiceLocationID"="OrganizationContacts"."cmcContactID")) LEFT OUTER JOIN "M1_L1"."dbo"."Organizations" "Organizations" ON "Shipments"."smpCustomerOrganizationID"="Organizations"."cmoOrganizationID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "M1_L1"."dbo"."Projects" "Projects" ON "Shipments"."smpProjectID"="Projects"."prpProjectID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "M1_L1"."dbo"."SalesOrders" "SalesOrders" ON "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderID"="SalesOrders"."ompSalesOrderID") INNER JOIN "M1_L1"."dbo"."SalesOrderLines" "SalesOrderLines" ON ("ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderID"="SalesOrderLines"."omlSalesOrderID") AND ("ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderLineID"="SalesOrderLines"."omlSalesOrderLineID")) INNER JOIN "M1_L1"."dbo"."SalesOrderDeliveries" "SalesOrderDeliveries" ON ("SalesOrderLines"."omlSalesOrderID"="SalesOrderDeliveries"."omdSalesOrderID")And ("ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderDeliveryID"="SalesOrderDeliveries"."omdSalesOrderDeliveryID")WHERE  "Shipments"."smpShipmentID"='16817'ORDER BY "Shipments"."smpShipmentID", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderID", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderLineID", "ShipmentLines"."smlSalesOrderDeliveryID", "ShipmentLines"."smlShipmentLineID"
```

I tried adding via Command but it breaks other aspects of my report and I am not sure the client program will be able to send the correct parameters to the report using command.

Please help!

Comment: This has been solved. You click on the database expert and select Links and then on the diagram of the tables you can click on a link and edit the relationship of the join.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. You click on the database expert and select Links and then on the diagram of the tables you can click on a link and edit the relationship of the join.